# I wanna output an error message in my gridview

Tags: gridview

When I don't click any check box to delete ,I want to output an error message "Please choose at least one or two check box to delete ? " in my gridview. How can I make ? Help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: When do you want this message? On click of a button? On loading the grid?

Comment: on click of a button...

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle  VerticalAlign ="Middle" />
```

http://forums.asp.net/p/1918653/5441206.aspx?How+to+display+error+message+in+GridView+